# Start button, charms bar not working after registry clean

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu, charms-bar

I used Advanced System Optimizer in Windows 8.1 to do a system scan, clean registry, defragment disk etc. Now start button and the button on bottom right that shows the desktop doesn't do anything when clicked. Also charms bar doesn't show up when mouse is hovered to top right or by pushing windows key + c. I think registry clean caused these problems. I tried enabling charms bar hint by modifying [registry](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15538-charms-bar-hint-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html), executing dism [command](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9585b847-afd8-4e66-931b-c6fda059dd79/windows-81-upgrade-from-8-start-button-does-not-work?forum=w8itproinstall), restoring pc to the oldest point and none worked. Any ideas?

Comment: The registry doesn't need to be cleaned, and I wouldn't recommend using such "optimizers" anyway. Do you get the same issues if you create a new account?

Comment: I couldn't create a new account. When I click "Add a new user in PC settings" at Manage Accounts, error window with explorer.exe as title appears saying "Class not registered". So I turned on guest user and tried that but same issues happen.

Comment: It looks like the system got seriously messed up. Consider [refreshing your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).

Comment: Thanks, refreshing PC worked and it's easier than formatting. I won't mess with registry anymore.

Comment: Only good optimizer is the CCLeaner, but the best thing is never to mess with the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Refreshing the PC

You did the basic troubleshooting steps already, but it looks like the system got seriously messed up. Consider doing a system refresh:

> If your PC isn't performing as well as it once did, and you don't know why, you can refresh your PC without deleting any of your personal files or changing your settings.
>
> **Note**
>
> If you upgraded your PC from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and your PC has a Windows 8 recovery partition, refreshing your PC will restore Windows 8. You’ll need to upgrade to Windows 8.1 after the refresh has finished.
>
> **Warning**
>
> Apps you installed from websites and DVDs will be removed. Apps that came with your PC and apps you installed from the Windows Store will be reinstalled. Windows puts a list of removed apps on your desktop after refreshing your PC.
>
> **To refresh your PC**
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap **Settings**, and then tap **Change PC settings**.
>    (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click **Settings**, and then click **Change PC settings**.)
> 2. Tap or click **Update and recovery**, and then tap or click **Recovery**.
> 3. Under **Refresh your PC without affecting your files**, tap or click **Get started**.
> 4. Follow the instructions on the screen.
>
> <sub>Source: [How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)</sub>

### Further reading

- [How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)
- [How to Refresh Windows 8 and Windows 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2293-refresh-windows-8-a.html)

---

## Windows registry

The registry doesn't need to be cleaned. Avoid using such "optimizers," because they can do more harm than good, as you noticed.

> The Windows‌ registry is a database that lists all of the configuration settings that determine how Windows looks and behaves. Sometimes, settings that are no longer needed will remain in the registry in case they're ever needed again. There's nothing unusual about this, and this data is small in size.
>
> [...] Although a registry setting can become corrupt on occasion, in general, the registry is self-sufficient.
>
> <sub>Source: [Are registry cleaners necessary?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/are-registry-cleaners-necessary#1TC=windows-7)</sub>

### Further reading

- [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)
- [Using Registry Cleaner: Does Is It Really Make A Difference?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/registry-cleaner-difference/)
- [Why Using a Registry Cleaner Won't Speed Up Your PC or Fix Crashes](http://www.howtogeek.com/171633/why-using-a-registry-cleaner-wont-speed-up-your-pc-or-fix-crashes/)

Comment: I still can't quite follow if it blows away your installed programs or not. If you've installed something big, like Photoshop, do you have to reinstall from media or is the installation preserved?

Comment: Why not try System Restore (not "refresh") first? It just sets your OS and registry back to the last time a restore point was taken, which by default is no more than a week ago.